# Is it possible to disable the bottom of a paint with stroke style programmatically

Tags: java, android, border, paint

I'm using a custom Class which extends ShapeDrawable to draw programmatically background and border with custom colors.

The code :

```
public class CustomBorderDrawable extends ShapeDrawable {
private Paint fillpaint, strokepaint;
private int WIDTH = 3;

public CustomBorderDrawable(Shape s) {
    super(s);
    fillpaint = this.getPaint();
    strokepaint = new Paint(fillpaint);
    strokepaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    strokepaint.setStrokeWidth(WIDTH);
    strokepaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Shape shape, Canvas canvas, Paint fillpaint) {
    shape.draw(canvas, fillpaint);
    shape.draw(canvas, strokepaint);
}

public void setFillColour(int c){
    fillpaint.setColor(c);
}

public void setBorderColour(int c){
    strokepaint.setColor(c);
}

public void setStrokeWidth(int px){
    this.WIDTH = px;
    strokepaint.setStrokeWidth(WIDTH);
}

public void setBottomEnable(boolean enable){
    //TODO
}}
```

As you can see I want to add a function which allow to enable or not the bottom part of my strokepaint.

I have only found XML solution, how to do that programmatically?

A solution could be to put a bar in front of the bottom of my border, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable the stroke then call **setStrokeWidth(0)**. Setting Width as 0 will not display the stroke.

Comment: I don't want to disable all the stroke, I want to disable only the bottom part

Comment: You can enable and disable bottom line by drawing rectangle on your shape using canvas.drawRect(). You will have to do calculation of start and end point according to your shape. Call canvas.drawRect in OnDraw() with you condition.

Comment: thank @Sonam, but like I said, I have no idea how to do that... I never use paint, canvas and other tool to draw in android. Can you give me a research track or a tuto for newbie like me ?

Comment: You can check http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e5156/learn-about-how-to-draw-rectangle-using-canvas-in-android-us/ link to learn how to draw a rectangle using canvas.drawRect()